# create a tree structure in java using hierarchical data from database

Tags: java, mysql, dom, hierarchy

I have this problem at hand which is as follows :

There is a many-to-many relationship between User & Group.The back-end has tables for the respective entity classes as well as an intersection table User_Groups which stores information about the association of a user to groups.The Groups table has two columns which are relevant to the problem at hand.The Structure of group table is as follows:

---

```
Table name - GROUP

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
GROUP
(
  GROUP_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  NAME VARCHAR(50) NULL ,
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(50) NULL ,
  CREATED_DATE DATE NULL ,
  CREATED_BY VARCHAR(50) NULL ,
  MODIFIED_DATE DATE NULL ,
  MODIFIED_BY VARCHAR(50) NULL ,
  GROUP_TYPE_ID INT NULL ,
  PARENT_GROUP_ID INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (GROUP_ID) ,
  INDEX fk_groupTypeId_idx (GROUP_TYPE_ID ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT fk_groupTypeId  FOREIGN KEY (GROUP_TYPE_ID )  
  REFERENCES efc_group_type (GROUP_TYPE_ID )
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Table name - USER_GROUPS

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
EFC_USER_GROUPS 
(
  USER_ID int(11) NOT NULL,
  GROUP_ID int(11) NOT NULL,
  CREATED_DATE date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID,GROUP_ID),
  KEY FK_USERID_idx (USER_ID),
  KEY FK_GROUPID_idx (GROUP_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_GROUPID_USERGROUPS FOREIGN KEY (GROUP_ID) 
  REFERENCES efc_group (GROUP_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_USERID_USERGROUPS FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) 
  REFERENCES efc_user (USER_ID));
```

---

The `parent_group_id` is basically acting as a foreign column to the `group_id`. A group can have sub-groups and hence the need to store the `parent_group_Id`. For each sub-group added, we store the `parent_group_id` for that group under which sub-group was added. Now that you have some idea about the data model, I'll illustrate what my problem is:

I am trying to construct a tree like structure for the parent-child relationship between groups & sub-groups for a certain user. So corresponding to a certain `user Id`, I am able to get the groups that he is part of from the `user_groups` table.Then I am able to filter the groups into two lists, one representing the parent nodes and the other has all child nodes. Now the hierarchy between groups is stored in the group table. I am not able to figure out how to implement that in java. I already have the list with me but in that list each group can have parents above it and also children below it. I am not able to understand how to build the top to bottom hierarchy. My sole purpose is to build that XML constituting the parent-nodes down to last child node and send it to the front-end.

P.S : I have googled quite a bit.I am running short of ideas :(. Please help me

Comment: If it helps,I am trying to implement hierarchical relationship.

Comment: Try googling for 'nested sets'. To get you started: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model